# Can I visit other countries with just my Italian carta di soggiorno?

Tags: visas, italian-residents

I have an Italian *carta di soggiorno*. What countries can I travel to with just this card? Can I travel to Edinburgh or Ireland? I'm told that if you have a *carta di soggiorno* to stay long term in the EU, you don’t need a visa to travel to Ireland.

Answer (score 4):

Your Italian residence permit allows you to travel within the Schengen area and to the Schengen-candidate EU members (Bulgaria, Croatia, Cyprus, and Romania).  It does not allow you to travel to the United Kingdom (where Edinburgh is), nor to Ireland.

Ireland is a member of the European Union, as was the UK when this question was asked.  For travel to Ireland, the residence permit exempts you from the requirement to have a visa only if the following are true:

- The card states that it was issued because you are the family member of a European Union citizen.
- You are traveling with your EU-citizen family member or joining him or her.

This visa exemption is no longer valid for the UK.  If you are the family member of an EU/EEA/Swiss citizen who is a participant in the EU Settlement Scheme, see [Traveller's answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/181509/19400) for the relevant details concerning travel to the UK.

Comment: Some countries also allow visa-free entry for holders of Schengen residence permit (f.e. Georgia and Albania).

Comment: Since Brexit, the UK rules https://www.gov.uk/guidance/visiting-the-uk-as-an-eu-eea-or-swiss-citizen now state: *If you’re a non-EEA family member of an EU, EEA or Swiss citizen
You need a valid national passport, and one of the following:

- an EU Settlement Scheme family permit
- a UK-issued EEA family permit
- a UK-issued biometric residence card.                            

You cannot use an Article 10 or Article 20 residence card issued by an EEA member state.*

Comment: @Traveller thanks, I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

With an ordinary Italian residence Permit (together with a passport), regardless of your nationality, you can visit (at least) Schengen countries, Albania, Bosnia, Bulgaria, Croatia, Cyprus, the Dominican Republic, Georgia, Kosovo, Montenegro, Romania and Serbia.

It does not let you visit the UK or Ireland.

Answer (score 1):

With effect from Jan 2021, to travel to Edinburgh (the UK), a non-EEA family member of an EU, EEA or Swiss citizen needs a valid national passport, and one of the following:

- an EU Settlement Scheme family permit
- a UK-issued EEA family permit
- a UK-issued biometric residence card

You cannot use an Article 10 or Article 20 residence card issued by an EEA member state.

Source: https://www.gov.uk/guidance/visiting-the-uk-as-an-eu-eea-or-swiss-citizen